# Cannot find MySQL -- get "command not found" error when trying to access MySQL from command line

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, ssh, command

I have previously installed, connected and uploaded to a [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) MySQL database via SSH no problem.  The people who run my server made a few configuration changes, and now I get a "bash: mysql: command not found" error when I try to log into MySQL via the command line on the same server to access the same database.

I am relatively new to all of this, so I am really not sure what to do.  When I run "which mysql" I get a message that says there is no MySQL executable in the */usr/bin* directories.  I can verify that MySQL is running between the fact that my site is still live and functioning and when I ran a command to test MySQL, I got a message that said "MySQL works!"

I find MySQL files in several directories, but I'm not really sure what I am looking for and how I connect to it when I do find it.  I am also not sure if this is user error, or if somehow someone moved or hid MySQL from me -- likely user error??

Comment: what do you get if you run `find / -iname 'mysql'`

Comment: it's better put this question to serverfault or superuser, i'm think.

Answer (score 16):

A MySQL *server* is not a MySQL *client*.

Check if MySQL is running by executing this command:

```
ps aux | grep mysql | grep -v grep
```

And install the MySQL client:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client # Or your distribution command
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have MySQL server up and running on your server, it does not mean you have a MySQL client installed on this server.

Try

```
ls -l /usr/bin/mysql*
```

Do you see MySQL binaries exactly present on system?

One more problem: Linux has very strange behaviour when you run binaries for another architecture.

For example, if you run a 32-bit executable on 64-bit system you will get an error message like "command or file not found", even if the binaries are actually present!

Answer (score 3):

Now *mysql-client* has changed to *default-mysql-client*.

Hence the command:

```
sudo apt-get install default-mysql-client
```

Answer (score 0):

Although MySQL is running, if you are not able to connect to the server using the `mysql` command, then you might be missing to provide soft links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin /usr/bin

sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/bin
```

This should enable you to connect.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get MySQL CLI working or to access the `mysql` command from anywhere, there are a set of steps to be done to add it to the `$PATH` variable.

First, open a terminal, and run the following command

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then to reload the Bash profile, run

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Now run,

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter the password which you gave during installation. You should see the following result:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

Answer (score -1):

You sometimes need to install MySQL on the local machine as well. That means, if you have a host running a MySQL Docker container, the strange thing happened to me that I needed to install mysql-server on the host as well, not only in the container.

The reason was that there was a shell script that needed to check the right database name from a query. In your case, it might be something different. On your host machine (which might even be your local computer, depending the your setup), if on Linux, try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Then you will get rid of

```
/home/.../some_bash_script.sh: line 123: mysql: command not found
```